# Type inference of inherited classes

Tags: typescript

I have an inheritance class similar to the following

```
class A {
  clone(): A {
    return new A()
  }
  methodA() {
    return this.clone()
  }
}

class B extends  A {
  clone(): B{
    return new B()
  }
  methodB(): B {
    return this.clone()
  }
}
const a = new B

a.clone().methodA().methodB()
```

I hope that calling 'methoda' in B should return a cloned object of B. in fact, this is effective. However, type inference thinks that even calling 'methoda' in B will still return a, resulting in the last line of code

Comment: Even if you call your variable a, it is an instance of B. Since B subclasses A, it will have its parent methods, like methodA, but const a will remain a B instance, thus methodA returns a B instance

Comment: @crissal: OPs issue is not related to `a` being `B`, in fact, they clearly state that this works as it should. The issue is actually `Property 'methodB' does not exist on type 'A'.` The `methodA` returns instance of `B` as you point out but it does it in run time. For the compiler, the `methodA` returns `A` and thus it lacks `methodB`. In other words, this code would work in plain Javascript but Typescript refuses to type it.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WP9g5w) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? Please @jcalz mention me if you reply; I won't be notified if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

In the light of [this ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841), you won't be able to do what you want.

You cannot write a method that will return a new instance of whatever subclass you're calling from (`new this()`).